# Solr search relevance boost and bf weighting not working with content^1

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I need to fine tune my search relevance and weighting as results returned are:

- not relevant to the search
- title search does not return matching listings to the top

**Solr** config snippet of request handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="defType">edismax</str>
  <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  <int name="rows">10</int>
  <str name="df">text</str>
  <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
  <str name="q.op">AND</str>
  <str name="qf">title^15.0 description^9.0 categoryNames^3.0 authorName^1.0 content^1.0</str>
  <str name="boost">scoreA</str>
</lst>
<lst name="appends">
  <str name="fq">private:false</str>
  <str name="fq">deleted:false</str>
  <str name="fq">draft:false</str>
</lst>
```

**Solr** schema snippets:

```
<field name="content" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="title" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="description" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="url" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="authorId" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="authorName" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <copyField source="title" dest="text"/>
  <copyField source="description" dest="text"/>
  <copyField source="content" dest="text"/>

<fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

twigkit search query:

```
<search:query var="query" type="all" parameters="*" resultsPerPage="18" sorts="-scoreA" fields="id,url,price,title,description,recommended,modifiedDate,downloadCount:field(downloadCount),ratingAverage:field(ratingAverage),ratingCount:field(ratingCount),scoreA:field(scoreA),scoreB:field(scoreB),viewCount:field(viewCount),authorName,authorId,content,categoryNames">
</search:query>

<search:response var="response" platform="${platform}" query="${query}"></search:response>
```

**My findings so far:**
If I remove the content^1 weighting from **Solr** qf params, then relevance search and title search works perfectly. Getting expected results.

BUT if I keep the content^1 weighting in **Solr** qf then it all goes wrong.

**Issue could be related to this but not sure:**

In the Solr schema, I have content type as:

```
type="text_en_splitting"
```

This field type has this filter applied:

```
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
```

When running the analyzer in solr console with index and query value: 
    first world war complete unit

I can see when it gets to the above filter, the value is:

```
first world war complet unit
```

The 'e' is omitted from the 'complete' word.

**Here's a snippet of the response in solr when 'content^1' is in the qf:**

```
"responseHeader": {
"status": 0,
"QTime": 187,
"params": {
  "lowercaseOperators": "true",
  "spellcheck": "true",
  "facet": "true",
  "sort": "scoreA desc",
  "indent": "true",
  "qf": "title^15.0 description^9.0 categoryNames^3.0 authorName^1.0 content^1",
  "spellcheck.collate": "true",
  "wt": [
    "json",
    "javabin"
  ],
  "hl": "true",
  "version": "2",
  "defType": "edismax",
  "rows": "18",
  "fl": "id,url,price,title,description,recommended,modifiedDate,downloadCount:field(downloadCount),ratingAverage:field(ratingAverage),ratingCount:field(ratingCount),scoreA:field(scoreA),scoreB:field(scoreB),viewCount:field(viewCount),authorName,authorId,content,categoryNames,score",
  "start": "0",
  "q": "world wars",
  "q.op": "AND",
  "_": "1429801074587",
  "facet.field": [
    "categories",
    "categoryRoot",
    "resourceTypes",
    "fileTypes",
    "recommended",
    "licence"
  ],
  "stopwords": "true"
}
```

**FURTHER FINDINGS:**

When searching with query 'world war', the word 'war' is being weighted heavily as it's found a lot of times in the first few listings attachments. It seems like the score is getting boosted if the word 'war' is found as a word on its own or as part of another word. Example, 'war' and 'beware'.

I just need content score to be boosted when 'war' is found as a whole word and not do anything if found within other words. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: why do you need this weighting?

Comment: if nothing else matches (title, description etc) except some stuff in the attachment 'content' from my search query then this should be returned high in search.

Comment: When you talk about removing the `content^1` weighting, do you mean you are taking the `content` field out of the `qf` entirely, or just taking off the `^1`? You might also want to add more detail about what you mean when you say it **"works perfectly"** without the weighting but **"it all goes wrong"** with it. What goes wrong? Do you get an error message, or is it that your relevance order doesn't work correctly?

Comment: the content field is out of the qf entirely. when i say works perfect, i mean the search relevance and title search ordering is correct without the content field in qf. When it's in qf, relevance order is way off the mark. Getting irrelevant results returned on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The final solution to this issue turned out to be instead of `sort=scoreA desc` to use `sort=score desc&boost=scoreA`. This uses the boost value of `scoreA` as a multiplier to the Solr `score`, then sorts using the `score` which takes into account Solr's own relevance math and the boost value. The original answer and the conversation that led to this conclusion follows.

It sounds like you are happy with the relative weight of the other fields but even with the lower weight, content is *too* relevant compared to the other fields.

The most likely solution is to adjust the weights, either lowering the weight for content, or raising the weight for the other fields. Maybe `content^0.1` would give you the results you want. If your only purpose for including the content field is to find matches there when there are no matches to be found in more important places, then setting an extremely low relative weight will ensure that "content" matches will never outweigh matches in other fields.

In general, I find [solr.explain.pl](http://explain.solr.pl/) to be a useful tool for debugging Solr relevancy. It takes your query results from a test Solr query where you have activated the optional relevancy explanation output, and gives you a graphical representation of how the relevancy is determined for each result document. It doesn't deal well with complex queries with their own logical operators, but with a simple test query it can be a big help understanding how the relevance order is determined so you can adjust it appropriately.

---

edit: Now that you've added the response snippet, I notice that you are using `q.op=AND`, but that's a feature of the [Standard Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser). Since you're using the [Extended Dismax Query Parser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser), you ought to be using the `mm` ([Minimum Match](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Themm%28MinimumShouldMatch%29Parameter)) argument instead. `mm=100%` is the equivalent of `q.op=AND` for the Dismax and Extended Dismax Query Parsers. I don't know if this is related to the issue you're having, but it could be.

Comment: I've tried with different weightings but still wouldn't solve problem. I tried with title^150.0 description^90.0 categoryNames^30.0 authorName^1.0 content^0.1 but still get the same results. Results only change when content is removed from qf.

Comment: Did you try looking at the "explain" data? It can really help to see a which fields are contributing to the score of each result and how much.

Comment: I just added a bit to my answer based on the response snippet you added to the question.

Comment: how do i get the full raw solr response?

Comment: I usually get raw Solr responses by forming queries directly in my browser. I assumed that's how you got the snipped you posted. You can also get additional debug information with the added argument `debugQuery=true`.

Comment: i got that snippet from solr web console query form

Comment: using solr 4.1, which is not supported by the explain tool so cannot use that.

Comment: I have used the explain tool for versions 4.2 and 4.9 even though they are not on the list of supported versions. It has worked fine when not using complex logical queries, even though the site doesn't list anything over version 3.5 as "supported". My suggestion is to try it anyway.

Comment: checked their help section and they mentioned it there. supported up to 3.5

Comment: Sorry... I should have deleted my comment and posted a new one when I figured out why you were saying 4.1 isn't supported. I do encourage you to try it anyway. It works for me.

Comment: managed to get results from explain, can you take a look at it please http://explain.solr.pl/explains/tpegv9sv

Comment: It looks like your top result only has the words "world" and "war" in the content block. This record has a **very** low score, but it's coming up first because you aren't actually sorting on your relevance scores. Instead of `sort=scoreA desc` can you try `sort=score desc`?

Comment: I'll try that in a min. is there a problem also because i'm using the 'df' field and 'qf' field together?

Comment: sorting by score desc gives very good results and it looks good BUT does this score include my optional boost score as well? (scoreA)

Comment: Probably not. If you want to use scoreA as a boost value, then with `edismax` I would suggest `boost=scoreA` as a separate argument.

Comment: https://docs.lucidworks.com/display/MODULES/Relevancy+Workbench+Parameters looks like boost score is added to the document score so i think we are good to go with score desc

Comment: About your other question, `df` isn't used by edismax, so my guess is the value is being completely ignored, though it would come into play if you ever switched to the standard/Lucene query parser.